# making an angular function that returns a remote data and waiting for promises to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I understand that the traditional way to wait for remote data is to .then from promises but the Problem is I need to create a function that returns the value created by the .then

```
//inside controller
$scope.someFunction = function(id){
   var returnVal;
   $http.post(someURL,{_id:id}).then(
       function(r){
           //lets assume r.data = {id:123,name:'john doe'}
           returnVal = r.data.name;
       },function(r){
           console.error(r.statusText);
           returnVal = 'error getting name'
       }    
   );
   return returnVal;
};
```

The problem is it keeps returning a null result because it executes the return block even when .then was not called yet.

```
//the html is like this
<main component>
    <!--this main component will generate dynamic number of subs-->
    <!--lets assume Seller is the main and sub is all the products he sold -->
    <sub component sub-detail="the function that returns correct value">
        <!--I need to make $http request to get the product details for each product generated-->
    </sub component>
</main component>
<another main component>
    <!--generates another series of subs-->
</another main component>
```

so in short. I need a function() that returns data from an http request

Comment: What's the point of calling a function (`http.post`) that runs _async_ if you want the outer function to be synchronous?

Comment: I am using a telerik component that generates another sub-component. It allows me to specify the attributes before it generates the sub-component but I need to get the data from a remote service.

Comment: If this is in controller why are you needing to return anything and not just assign scope model properties within the callback?

Comment: because the generated sub-component is not visible while coding the html. It needs to have dynamic data.

Comment: So does everything in angular, what makes yours different? Provide [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps you should look to using a routing resolve...or just pass the promise to your other component

Comment: I would love to do that, but what if it generates thousands of sub components?

Comment: can you remove the duplicate mark @charlie?

Comment: Show the js related to component and explain what you need from the controller first. This is turning into a completely different XY Problem question. Also a routing `resolve` would do exactly what you want to have data there before view renders

Comment: I can't, I signed a non-disclosure agreement(this project is from my internship btw), I edited my question to show a pseudo-code of the actual html

Comment: Well without [mcve] is hard to help solve whatever problem is

Answer (score -2):

Update your code:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(id){
   var returnVal;
   return $http.post(someURL,{_id:id}).then(
       function(r){
           //lets assume r.data = {id:123,name:'john doe'}
           returnVal = r.data.name;
           return returnVal;
       },function(r){
           console.error(r.statusText);
           returnVal = 'error getting name';
           return returnVal;
       }    
   );
};
```

Comment: That still returns a promise that must be `.then`ed.

Comment: try it and comment it. you haven't try it right? I did in my local and works. will show you a minute in plunkr. just looking for dummy post source

Comment: Sure, it works. It just doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement.

Comment: could you underline here. what is the OP's requirement? in my perspective he/she want to solve about 'returning a null result because it executes the return block even when .then was not called yet.'  put it in the bold would be good.

Comment: @mparnisari why don't you add more detail about your comment into the answer. so be more clear for me about your concern 'doesn't satisfy OP's requirement' you could do it right?

Comment: The OP wants the raw result from the HTTP call. Your code returns a promise (`return $http.post`..)

Comment: @mparnisari and what do you propose differently?